# Executing code after a process is done - jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, load, click, live

I want to run:

```
$(".left").load("created.php");
```

after:

```
$("#placeholder").load("create.php")
```

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
$("#create").live("click", function() {
 if($("#placeholder").load("create.php")) {
  $(".left").load("created.php");
 }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function runs asychronously.  You need to use a **callback function** to run code *after* the first load completes.

The following code should suffice:

```
 $("#create").live("click", function() {
   $("#placeholder").load("create.php", function() {
     $(".left").load("created.php");
   });
 });
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

call the `created.php` in the call back of first load

```
$("#placeholder").load("create.php",null,function(){

$(".left").load("created.php");

});
```

[`jquery load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#placeholder").load("create.php"))
```

this line means load create.php then return a jqxhr object which is not what you mean.
use callback of load method: $("#placeholder").load("create.php", function(data){...})
Or
use $.when and .then instead

Answer (score 0):

Execute it in the success handler of the previous `load`

```
$("#placeholder").load("create.php", function(){
   $(".left").load("created.php");
});
```